# I can't understand the proof of pancake therom (Ham sandwich theorem for $n=2$)

Tags: general-topology

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem

> part in Two-dimensional variant: proof using a rotating-knife

I understand by intermediate value theorem for any angle exist a positon that cut pancake#1 and for any position there exist an angle cut pancake#2.

but I don't know how does conclude to the final proof. It doesn't look like a complete proof for me.
how does it proof there exist an angle and position whitch cut pancake#1 and #2 **simultaneity**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly do you not understand. Which part of the article are you referring to?

Comment: @IraeVid I have reedited the question please let me know If my description is still unclear.